# Changing from useRouteMatch to useMatch / useLocation

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Looking at the documentation for react-router 6, the useRouteMatch hook was removed in favor of useMatch. Since the in v5 useRouteMatch either

> takes no argument and returns the match object of the current `<Route>` or takes a single argument

Does that mean that when useRouteMatch is used without an argument I could just use the pathname from useLocation? And should I still pass that to useMatch?

Example of what I'm trying to convert to version 6 (v5 code):

```
const match = useRouteMatch();
if (!match) return null;
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:Id?`} component={ImportedComponent} />
  </Switch>
);
```

Changing this to v6:

```
const match = useMatch(); // which argument does this take?
if (!match) return null;
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:Id?`} element={<ImportedComponent />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Comment: Is the migration guide not clear? https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch

Comment: Not completely, for me. My guess is yes to both my questions

Comment: Your post is unclear. What specific issue are you trying to resolve for in upgrading from RRDv5 to RRDv6? See [mcve].

Comment: I've upated my question with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The `useMatch` Hook

`useMatch` takes a single path pattern argument, and returns a `PathMatch` object or null if there is a match to the current location, e.g. the current URL path.

Example:

Given the current location is `"/test/foo/bar"`.

- `useMatch("/test/foo/bar");` returns:

  ```
  {
    params: {},
    pathname: "/test/foo/bar",
    pathnameBase: "/test/foo/bar",
    pattern: {
      path: "/test/foo/bar",
      caseSensitive: false,
      end: true,
    },
  }
  ```
- `useMatch("/test/:segment1/:segment2");` returns:

  ```
  {
    params: {
      segment1: "foo",
      segment2: "bar",
    },
    pathname: "/test/foo/bar",
    pathnameBase: "/test/foo/bar",
    pattern: {
      path: "/test/:segment1/:segment2",
      caseSensitive: false,
      end: true,
    },
  }
  ```
- `useMatch("/bizzbuzz");` returns:

  ```
  null
  ```

## Rendering Descendent Routes

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Routes` component will "build" the paths it manages all relative to it's parent's `Route` component's path. There's no need to build these paths yourself manually. If the parent path is not currently matched then the component is not rendered and the `Routes` and descendent routes are not rendered.

Example:

Parent

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/child/*" element={<Child />} />
  ...
</Routes>
```

Child

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/:Id?" element={<ImportedComponent />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Here the `Child` component will be rendered whenever `"/child/*"` is the match. The route on `path="/:Id?"` will be matched and render its `element` content when it's a match. Since `Id` is an optional parameter this route will match `"/child"`, `"/child/123"`, and any other sub-route of `"/child"`.

### Demo

[image: Edit changing-from-useroutematch-to-usematch-uselocation]